multi-module maven project - how to build some of the modules
we have following scenario
parent pom contains
<packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>mod1</module> <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
    <module>mod2</module> <!--<packaging>pom</packaging>-->
    <module>mod3</module> <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
    <module>mod4</module> <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
  </modules>

mod2 depends on mod1 and contains
<packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
    <module>mod21</module> <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
    <module>mod22</module> <!--<packaging>jar</packaging>-->
  </modules>

need to build mod1 and both mods from mod2 (all jars), without building all others (mod3, mod4, etc)
running
mvn clean install -pl mod1,mod2

produces jar for mod1, but does not produce jars for mod21/mod22
what is correct maven command to achieve it ?
as workaround we use profiles, but want to know if its possible to do differently
UPD1:
mvn clean install -pl mod1,mod2

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mod1                                                               [jar]
[INFO] mod2                                                               [pom]
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.example:mod1 >--------------------------
[INFO] Building mod1 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                         [1/2]
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:resources (default-resources) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Copying 0 resource from src/main/resources to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file with javac [debug target 17] to target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.1:testResources (default-testResources) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod1/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.2.2:test (default-test) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod1/target/mod1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ mod1 ---
[INFO] Installing /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod1/pom.xml to /home/uzer/.m2/repository/org/example/mod1/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mod1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod1/target/mod1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/uzer/.m2/repository/org/example/mod1/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mod1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< org.example:mod2 >--------------------------
[INFO] Building mod2 1.0-SNAPSHOT                                         [2/2]
[INFO]   from /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod2/pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ mod2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ mod2 ---
[INFO] Installing /home/uzer/workspace/multi-module/mod2/pom.xml to /home/uzer/.m2/repository/org/example/mod2/1.0-SNAPSHOT/mod2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for mod1 1.0-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mod1 ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.657 s]
[INFO] mod2 ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.721 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-18T15:40:07+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------```


try mvn clean install -pl :mod1,:mod2

does not solve the problem
it produces mod1.jar and mod2.pom, and does not produce mod21.jar mod22.jar

Please add the build log to your question.

If you exactly know that you want to build mod2 and all its submodules, you can use mvn -f mod2 clean install.
The option -f helps you specify the root POM to consider for maven. In the suggestion above, it "focuses" maven on this module. It will build mod2 as well as its submodules mod21 and mod22.
However, suppose that mod3 also has submodules, because you can only specify one root file, you cannot use the option -f to build mod2 AND mod3 and their submodules.

problem that mod2 depends on mod1, that is why i need to build mod1 and mod2 together

Yes, that's what I was stating in my however section. If you need more than one entire submodule and its children, like you did with mod1 and mod2 and all below, I don't have a solution.
You can always decompose it by first building -pl mod1 and then -f mod2. But I assume that things are not as simple as your OP and therefore, I don't have any solution to offer.

You can always try the flag -amd that triggers the build for mod1 and mod2, and all modules depending on mod1 and mod2. However, this can trigger the build of mod3.
With the syntax !mod3, you can exclude certains modules from the build list, but it is a module-per-module solution, not encompassing the module's children
